# how would i separate a string based on some pattern without loosing the match parameter in python?

Tags: python, regex

this is the string i have (ignoring whitespace)

```
a = u'(%o3) (9*t*(7*t*(5*t*(3*t^2-1)/2-2*t)/3-3*(3*t^2-1)2)/4-4\r\n*(5*t*(3*t^2-1)2 \r\n-2*t)\r\n/3)\r\n /5\r\n(%i4) '
```

how would i split it into something like this:

```
b = ['(%o3','(9*t*(7*t*(5*t*(3*t^2-1)/2-2*t)/3-3*(3*t^2-1)2)/4-4\r\n*(5*t*(3*t^2-1)2\r\n-2*t)\r\n/3)\r\n /5','(%i4)' ]
```

its kind of like checking for the patterns (%o\d+) and (%i\d+)  and splitting  where they occur but not loosing the pattern itself, a.split( blah) will usually
 loose 'blah'. in my context the 'blah' is significant and i cant loose it.

there may be more than 2 occurrences of the patterns so i need to separate the
(%o\d+) and (%i\d+)   and any text in between them/before after them. 
whats the best way to do that? 
im not sure whether regexes can do that or an existing modification of  text.split that does not loose the split parameter would do (if it exists)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use capturing parenthesis around the match parameter re.split return the match parameter too.

```
print re.split('(\(%[oi]\d+\))', a)
```

More infos [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Comment: well it works fine, thanks it even works for b = a*2 ( a concatenated with itself). One more thing how would i get rid of empty strings after the match? it seems the match end up with some empty fields.

Answer (score 1):

## Description

In python you could use

[this link to regex](http://fiddle.re/8t506) `(\([%][a-z][0-9]{1,}\))(.*?)(\([%][a-z][0-9]{1,}\))$`

when applied against your string

```
(%o3)  (9*t*(7*t*(5*t*(3*t^2-1)/2-2*t)/3-3*(3*t^2-1)2)/4-4\r\n*(5*t*(3*t^2-1)2\r\n-2*t)\r\n/3)\r\n /5\r\n(%i4)
```

yields the following grouped matches

```
group(0) - the entire string
group(1) - (%o3)
group(2) - (9*t*(7*t*(5*t*(3*t^2-1)/2-2*t)/3-3*(3*t^2-1)2)/4-4\r\n*(5*t*(3*t^2-1)2\r\n-2*t)\r\n/3)\r\n /5\r\n
group(3) - (%i4)
```

## Summary

- `(` open the **first** group match
- `\(` require an open round bracket
- `[%]` require there is a percent sign
- `[a-z]` require any lower case alpha character
- `[0-9]{1,}` require any number of digits in any sequence
- `\)` require a close round bracket
- `)` close the **first**group
- `(` Open the **second** group match
- `.*?` match the entire center sub string between your open and close substrings
- `)` close the **second**group Match
- `(` open the **third** group match
- `\(` require an open round bracket
- `[%]` require there is a percent sign
- `[a-z]` require any lower case alpha character
- `[0-9]{1,}` require any number of digits in any sequence
- `\)` require a close round bracket
- `)` close the **third** group
- `$` ensure there is an end of string. This forces the third group to be at the end of the string and not hovering somewhere in the middle

## Disclaimers

In your source question it appears that the `\r\n` substring prior to the third group where dropped and there were some extra spaces included in your resulting text then where in the source text. I'm assuming those where introduced or dropped by accident.

Comment: it works for a string a like the one o gave, but i dont think it would work for a*2 properly, as i pointed out, i need it to work for more than one occurence.